# Calculate mathematical expression within string in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

How do I evaluate the mathematical expression within a string and assign it to a numerical value in angularJS?

Eg: var value = 10;

var someValue = "Math.min(value * 0.22, 106800)". I need someValue to be a valid integer of 2.2.

Is this something which can be done by angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `eval`.

```
var value = 10;
var someValue = eval("Math.min(value * 0.22, 106800)");
console.log(someValue);
```

And it will be printed in console

`2.2`

Comment: I would highly suggest not doing this if it's a dynamic string from user input. You might consider using Angular's $eval method instead.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be by injecting 'Math' into your scope and using it in say a controller

```
$scope.Math = window.Math;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxE79/1/

Comment: i like your solution better. you could run Math functions from the scope as well.. like this. http://jsfiddle.net/ayDAn/